# Looking for a study featuring a self-reflection growth/distribution curve

Tags: bias, moral-psychology, self, self-control

What I mean is a graph that would either feature:

- a histogram of self-reflection distribution in the general population
- a curve reflecting the growth in self-reflection resulting from a therapy or a self-improvement effort

I have a hypothesis such a curve should be exponential, as self-reflection [allows](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4613-2645-8_14) one to suppress the self-serving defensive mechanisms.

Comment: I am not aware of a measure called "self-reflection".  Do you mean amount of time spent in self-reflection? Quality of self-reflection (eg, rumination vs introspection vs meditation)? Healthiness of self-reflection (eg, using it appropriately)?

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg I mean introspection, the ability to be understand the roots of one's behavior.

Comment: A goal of some cognitive therapies is to identify and find healthier alternatives for cognitive distortions (rationalizations, defense mechanisms, etc).  If there was a way to measure how much of a patient's verbal reports feature cognitive distortions (presumably showing a decline over time), would that be what you are looking for?  @Ooker [previously asked](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/10943/7001) "is the concept scientific/measurable/falsifiable?" - is that the same question you have?

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg I'm afraid it's not, rationalization is only one of many possible distortions to one's ability to self-reflect and I'm interested in the dynamics of overcoming those defense mechanism, not the validity of its measures.

Comment: [Self-reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-reflection) and [introspection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introspection) do not refer to cognitive distortions.  Please use "cognitive distortions" if that's what you mean.  I literally said: "cognitive distortions (rationalizations, defense mechanisms, etc)" to which you replied: "rationalization is only one of many possible distortions".  What is not clear here?  How do you propose to graph the dynamics of cognitive distortions without a valid measure?

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg The question you linked was only regarding rationalization. Of course a valid measure is always nice, however that doesn't mean we cannot go any further past the question of validity.

Comment: For any fellow pilgrim of the internet, I've been able to find one paper on the dynamics of the development of self-reflection  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/301327159_Dynamic_development_of_psychological_structures_in_action_and_thought